# Setting Conditional Breakpoint for Pointer Value

Tags: pointers, gdb, conditional-statements, breakpoints

in gdb, how do i set a conditional breakpoint depending on value of pointer keeping in mind that i have to check if pointer is null before dereferencing pointer?

here is an example of code i'm trying to debug:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int *i[10];
  int *j = NULL;
  int k;

  i[4] = new int;
  *i[4] = 8;

  for (k=0; k < 10; k++) {
    j = i[k];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

i set conditional breakpoint at line "j=i[k]" but i got a seg fault:

```
(gdb) b 14 if j && *j == 8
(gdb) r
Starting program: /nfs/blahblah/a.out
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

does anybody know why there is a segfault?

Comment: If you type just `b 14`, what line does it stop at? For me (gcc 4.8.2),  it stops at line 16, `return 0`, because there's no code generated for line 14.

Comment: I can't reproduce the segfault. What compiler and OS version are you using?

Comment: I tried putting the conditional break point (same as the one in your question) at b 13 but no segfault.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unusual error message:

> Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.

I think perhaps something is wrong with your executable.  What does `file a.out` say?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what's causing the "Failed to read a valid object file image from memory" message, I think you meant to initialize the array `i` to all NULLS

```
int *i[10] = { 0 };
```

The code must be built with -O0 since local variable `j` is set but not used. Here's how the modified code works on my machine:

### t.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int *i[10] = { 0 };
  int *j = NULL;
  int k;

  i[4] = new int;
  *i[4] = 8;

  for (k=0; k < 10; k++) {
    j = i[k];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

### Sample Session

```
$ gcc -O0 t.cc -o t
$ gdb -q t
(gdb) b 13 if j && *j == 8
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:13
13      j = i[k];
```